# Rails Polymorphic joint table empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I'm creating an event system and having difficulty with my polymorphic association.

the events can be either be:

- **National** : broadcasted for the whole group (a group has many shops)
- **Local** : broadcasted for one or more shops

I have 2 types of jingles that will be broadcasted at the same time after reaching a threshold:

- **specific_media** : media broadcasted in the shop that reached the threshold
- **generic_media** : media broadcasted in the other shops of the group when the specific media is broadcasted in the shop that reached the treshold.

my models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :specific_media, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :generic__media, polymorphic: true
  has_many :event_join
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_joins, allow_destroy: true


class EventJoin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :event
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_joins, as: :eventable
  has_many :events,
           :through => :event_joins
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_joins, as: :eventable
  has_many :events, 
           :through => :event_joins
end
```

tables:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string  :title
      t.references :specific_media, polymorphic: true
      t.references :generic_media, polymorphic: true
      t.string  :created_by_id
      t.string  :updated_by_id
      t.float   :threshold
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :events
  end
end


class CreateEventJoins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :event_joins do |t|
      t.integer :event_id
      t.references :eventable, polymorphic: true
      t.boolean :is_active, default: true
      t.string  :created_by
      t.string  :updated_by
    end
   add_index :event_joins, [:eventable_id, :eventable_type]
  end

  def down
    drop_table :event_joins
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
  def index
    @search   = Search.new(params[:search])
    @shop = find_user_shop(@search.shop_id)
    @events = @shop.events
  end

   def new
     @event = Event.new
   end

   def create
     @search   = Search.new(params[:search])
     @shop = find_user_shop(@search.shop_id)
     @events = @shop.events
     @event = @events.new(params[:event])
     if @event.save!
       flash.now[:notice] = "Votre événement a bien été enregistré"
       render :index
     else
       flash.now[:error] = "Erreur lors de l'enregistrement du événement"
       render :new
    end
  end
```

I want the eventable_type to be either Shop (local) or Group (national). So mainly what I want is when I type:

- Shop.first.events: I get all the local events (eventable_type: Shop)
- Group.first.events: I get all the national events (eventable_type: Group)

How can I do this ? Am I going wrong in this polymorphic association ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the join table:

**groups.rb**

```
# setup:
# $ gem install active_record
# $ gem install logger
# $ gem install pry
# $ gem install sqlite3
#
# run:
# $ ruby groups.rb

require 'active_record'
require 'logger'
require 'pry'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:'
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new $stdout
ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging = false

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  self.verbose = false

  create_table :events do |t|
    t.string  :title
    t.references :eventable, polymorphic: true, index: true
    t.string  :created_by_id
    t.string  :updated_by_id
    t.float   :threshold
  end

  create_table :shops do |t|
    t.integer :group_id
  end

  create_table :groups do |t|
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :events, as: :eventable
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops
  has_many :events, as: :eventable
end

group = Group.create

shop1 = group.shops.create
shop2 = group.shops.create


group.events.create(title: "Global Event: SpaceX Rocket Launch")

shop1.events.create(title: "Local Event: Son's Birthday")
shop2.events.create(title: "Local Event: Dinner Party")

# Associations you can try to verify it works:

# shop1.events
# shop2.events
# group.events
# shop1.group.events

binding.pry
```